# Output verbosity of cmdlets to GUI text box Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface, scripting, automation

Let's say I have a form with 1 button and 1 text box.  All the button does is use copy-item.  How would I get the output of that copy to the text box?  Even further I would like for it to do it in real time as if I were looking at the console.  If that's not possible then updating the text box after the command is executed is also fine.

Example:

```
function CreateFormButton ( $locationheight, $locationwidth, $sizeheight, $sizewidth, $fieldname, $functionname ) {
  $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
  $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($locationheight, $locationwidth) 
  $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizeheight, $sizewidth) 
  $Button.Text = $fieldname 
  $Button.Add_Click( $functionname ) 
  $Form.Controls.Add($Button) 
}

function CreateTextWindow ( $locationHeight, $LocationWidth, $TextBoxHeight, $TextBoxWidth, $name ) {
  $TextWindow = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
  $TextWindow.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($textBoxHeight,$textBoxWidth)
  $TextWindow.location = new-object system.drawing.point($locationHeight,$LocationWidth)
  #$textWindow.Text = "Complete"
  $TextWindow.Name = $name
  $TextWindow.Multiline = $true
  $Form.Controls.Add($TextWindow) 
}

$path1 = "C:\SomePath\"
$path2 = "C:\SomePath\"

function call_Clean
{
  #Edit
  #Copy-Item "$Path1\Unit" -Destination $Path2 -Recurse -Force  
  Copy-Item "$Path1\Unit" -Destination $Path2 -Recurse -Force -Verbose
}

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Tool"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (475, 600)
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4000, 300)



CreateFormButton 315 100 120 40 'Local Deploy' ${function:call_Clean}
CreateTextWindow 150 160 300 375 'TextBox'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Copy-Item` doesn't return any value. The action you would want to perform is a `Test-Path` after copying your item. Then you can set a custom value in the text box based on the True or False return from `Test-Path`

Example:

```
Copy-Item C:\myfolder\myfile.txt -Destination C:\myfolder2\myfile.txt
$result = Test-Path C:\myfolder2\myfile.txt
if($result)
{
    $MyTextBox.Text = "Item moved"
}
Else
{
    $MyTextBox.Text = "Item failed to move"
}
```

You can also add on `-PassThru` and assign that response to a variable.

Comment: I didnt add the -verbose flag to that copy-item statement I apologize.  I'm going to edit that but basically i'm looking for the output that the -verbose flag would give to be written to the text box.